# Copy rows from tables into another table in the *same document*

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I must not be understanding how tables are identified in Microsoft Word and so my attempt keeps failing.

I get a "Run-Time Error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist."

I am trying to take the second row of all tables except the first two and the last two (last is the summary table I am trying to create) and populate a final summary table.
The second row in the third table in the document will be the second row in the final summary table, then the second row in the fourth table in the document will be the third row in the final summary table, etc. (There will be about 30 rows with data).

I tried this subroutine (and many iterations e.g. Tables(t).Items.Rows(2).Select etc. that did not work)

```
Sub CopyTblsRow2ToTable()

  Dim t As Long
  Dim TableCount As Long
TableCount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

For t = 3 To TableCount - 2 'First two tables and last table
'copy row to Tables(TableCount)
'Tables.Item(t).Rows(2).Select
ActiveDocument.Tables(t).Rows(2).Range.Copy

ActiveDocument.Tables(TableCount).Rows(t - 1).Range.Paste

  Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Likely `Rows(t - 1)` doesn't correspond to a row in your Summary table.  If you start at table 3 there must be at least 2 rows already in your summary table.

Comment: I put 30 rows in the summary table.  It stalls on the first iteration.

Comment: This works fine for me as long as `ActiveDocument.Tables(TableCount)` has enough rows.

Comment: That was helpful! I found two issues, 1) I was not initiating the VBA at the top of the document, and 2) there were some single row tables being used (for some reason) as headers in the document.  I could add in some troubleshooting making sure there are two rows, etc. but this did what I needed for now.  Thanks Tim!

Comment: Now struggling with the fact this is appending instead of overwriting... sigh.

Comment: «I was not initiating the VBA at the top of the document» That would only matter if you were using Selection for the tables to process, but I see no evidence of that in the code snippet you posted. «Now struggling with the fact this is appending instead of overwriting» That is to be expected of a copy/paste (and the FormattedText method). If you're using existing cells, you have to process their content individually - excluding the end-of-cell markers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your destination table has just the header row, all you really need is:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, t As Long
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Tables(.Tables.Count).Range
  For t = 3 To .Tables.Count - 2
    If .Tables(t).Rows.Count > 1 Then
      Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Rng.FormattedText = .Tables(t).Rows(2).Range.FormattedText
    End If
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```